# linux - stopping systemd-networkd via dbus

Tags: python, docker, systemd

I have some python code running inside a docker container. I am mapping the host's systemd-networkd configuration directories to some folders inside the docker container, and I also have a dbus socket mapped into the docker container. my python code changes the host's networkd configuration files and then uses the dbus python API to stop and then start systemd-networkd on the host.

For some reason after a few second the systemd networkd process is restarted before I start it again, after about 5 seconds. However, this doesn't happen if I use "service stop systemd-networkd" on the host.

Is there any configuration I need to set to make it not restart itself when stopped via dbus?

Thanks.

Edit - I found the reason. I have a bond interface and I need to update it's configuration. networkd doesn't reload the bond configuration so I tried to delete the bond in my python code using ip link del. As soon as the bond is deleted systemd recognizes it and restarts networkd. This also happens if I use systemctl to stop systemd-networkd and delete the bond manually. Can I disable this behaviour and restore it after I delete the bond?

Comment: Can you add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of the issue, `Dockerfile` and `docker run` commands. Thanks

Comment: I think I discovered the reason. I'll edit the question.